# load data after the page load in livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Inside a view I have a livewire component that receives a list of coins from the api And are displayed inside the table.Now I want the page to load first and then load my component and display the list of coins.How can I do this? My code is such that data is received before the page loads

```php
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Backend\Crypto;

use Livewire\Component;

class Cryptolist extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        try {
            $api = new \Binance\API('api','secret');
            $prices = $api->coins();
            $one = json_encode($prices, true);

            $coins = json_decode($one , true);
            return view('livewire.backend.crypto.cryptolist')->with('coins' , $coins);
        }catch(\Exception $e)
        {
            return view('wrong')->with('e' , $e);
        }
    }
}
```

this is view

```php
@extends('backend.layouts.app')

@section('title', __('User Management'))

@section('breadcrumb-links')
    @include('backend.auth.user.includes.breadcrumb-links')
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="components">
        <div class="card card-bordered">
            <div class="card-inner">
                <livewire:backend.crypto.cryptolist />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- .card-preview -->
    </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

and this is component for show data :

```
<div wire:ignore wire:init="init">
    <div id="loadesh1">
    <table class="datatable-init nk-tb-list nk-tb-ulist" data-auto-responsive="false">
        <thead>
        <tr class="nk-tb-item nk-tb-head">
            <th class="nk-tb-col"><span class="sub-text">name</span></th>
            <th class="nk-tb-col tb-col-mb"><span class="sub-text">balance</span></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach ($coins as $item => $value)
            <tr class="nk-tb-item">
                <td class="nk-tb-col">
                    <div class="user-card">
                        <div class="user-avatar d-none d-sm-flex">

                            @if(file_exists(public_path() . '/img/crypto/'.strtolower($value['coin'].".svg")))
                                <img style="border-radius: 0" src="{{asset('/img/crypto/'.strtolower($value['coin']))}}.svg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                            @else
                                <img style="border-radius: 0" src="https://demo.rayanscript.ir/-/vendor/cryptocurrency-icons/32/color/noimage.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                            @endif

                        </div>
                        <div class="user-info">
                            <span class="tb-lead english" style="font-weight: bolder">{{$value['name']}}</span>
                            <span class="english">{{$value['coin']}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="nk-tb-col tb-col-mb" data-order="{{$value['coin']}}">
                    <div class="btn-group" aria-label="Basic example">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-dim btn-light" wire:click="getBalance('{{$value['coin']}}')">
                            <div wire:loading wire:target="getBalance('{{$value['coin']}}')">
                                <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </div>
                            <span class="w-120px" id="coin-{{$value['coin']}}">get balance</span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-dim btn-primary">add coin</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr><!-- .nk-tb-item  -->
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a directive in Livewire called `wire:init`. This accepts a method in your component that gets run after the first, initial render.

Declare a property in your class that determine if you should load data or not. Set it to false by default, and set it to true in your method that gets called on initialization.

Be cautious to set your other properties to a state where your view still renders without the data, as you see the code below sets an empty array before the initial load.

```php
class Cryptolist extends Component
{
    public bool $loadData = false;

    public function init()
    {
        $this->loadData = true;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        try {
            if ($this->loadData) {
                $api = new \Binance\API('api','secret');
                $prices = $api->coins();
                $one = json_encode($prices, true);

                $coins = json_decode($one , true);
            } else {
                $coins = [];
            }
            return view('livewire.backend.crypto.cryptolist')->with('coins' , $coins);
        }catch(\Exception $e)
        {
            return view('wrong')->with('e' , $e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the root element in your blade view, put

```
wire:init="init"
```

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/defer-loading

---

Seeing your view after your edit, and that you are having trouble with your `wire:ignore` - here's how to work around that: wrap your table and code that is supposed to be ignored, inside a conditional of `@if ($loadData)`. That way the Livewire component can re-render and push the table with the data after its loaded, and show a loading-text before the data is loaded.

```html
<div wire:init="init">
    @if ($loadData)
        <div id="loadesh1" wire:ignore>
            <table class="datatable-init nk-tb-list nk-tb-ulist" data-auto-responsive="false">
                <!-- Rest of your table -->
            </table>
        </div>
    @else
        Loading data...
    @endif
</div>
```

Comment: I wrote this code, but after loading the page, nothing happens and nothing loads

Comment: In the inspect element and the network tab, I noticed that the information was received but nothing was displayed in the table

Comment: Did you add `wire:init`? Sounds like you didn't. If yes, where did you put it?

Comment: Yes, I added it and it works because I saw in the network tab that the request was sent and the response was received, but the problem is that the information is not displayed in the table. I added it to the root element

Comment: You explicitly told Livewire to ignore changes to the view, with `wire:ignore`, so Livewire will not do any dom-diffing inside it. Remove `wire:ignore` and it will work. Another thing to note, you should have `wire:key` on your `<tr class="nk-tb-item">`, making it `<tr class="nk-tb-item" wire:key="coin-{{ $loop->index }}">`.

Comment: Yes, it's right, thank you
But when I delete `wire:ignore` , my datatable returns to simple table mode.
As if I did not use datatable at all !

Comment: See my updated answer on how to handle that.

Comment: Update your question then. With your actual, current code. That will work just fine if you do it right.

Comment: How about when using collections? If I get `$posts = Post::all()` and inside the `else` clause I set it as `$posts=[]`, then I get the following error: `Call to a member function links() on array`. Then if I try `$posts = collect()` or `$posts=null`, then I get another error: `Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::links does not exist` and `Call to a member function links() on null`, respectively. How do I fix it?

Comment: @Pathros The `links()` method only exists on Eloquent Collections, which are not the same as normal collections. Either check that it has data before using `links()`, or initialize an empty eloquent collection, `$posts = Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::make();`